# React Native with Redux issue with reducer for adding an item to favourties

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, reducers

I've been struggling for a long time with this one. I was trying to create a reducer to be able to add an item into a favourties list. I can create a state object and save down the id into the state object using useState, but have hit a brick wall trying to do the same with Redux.

this is my favicon.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import { View, TouchableOpacity,StyleSheet, Text, Alert } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { toggleFavId, isFavourite } from '../actions'

const FavIcon = ({recipeid, toggle, isFav, text}) => {

  const [isFavNew, setFavNew] = useState(false)
  const toggleFav = (recipeid) =>{
    setFavNew(!isFavNew)
    console.log(`Entered toggle ${recipeid} isfavnew = ${isFavNew}`)
  }

   return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.favItem} onPress={() => {toggleFav(recipeid)}}>
                <FontAwesome name={isFavNew == true ? 'heart' : 'heart-o'} size={40} color='red' />
               <Text> {text}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>({
    favids: state.favids,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    toggle: (recipeid) => dispatch(toggleFavId(recipeid)),
    isFav: (recipeid) => dispatch(isFavourite(recipeid)),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(FavIcon)
```

This is my reducer but its incorrect as I cant seem to be able to pull the state for an item.

```
import {TOGGLE, IS_FAVOURITE} from '../actions'

export const favids = (state=[], action) => {
    const {type, recipeid} = action

    const newRecipe = {
        id: recipeid,
        is_fav: false,
    }

    switch (type) {
        case TOGGLE: {
            if (state.includes(recipeid)===true) {
               return state.filter((state) => state.id !== recipeid)
            }
            else {
                return state.concat(recipeid)
            }
        }
        case IS_FAVOURITE: {
            return state.map(item=>{
                if(item.recipeid === recipeid){
                    item.is_fav = !item.is_fav
                }
            })
        }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I am trying to create the reducer to replicated the toggleFav function in the FavIcon.

**const toggleFav = (recipeid) =>{
setFavNew(!isFavNew)
console.log(`Entered toggle ${recipeid} isfavnew = ${isFavNew}`)
}**

All I am trying to do is toggle the recipe in the favourites if clicked on the icon.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
return state.map(item=>{
                if (item.recipeid === recipeid){
                    return { ...item, is_fav: !item.is_fav  }
                }
                return item;
            })
```

Also, general observation: this is a very old style of redux you are writing here.
If you are learning redux right now, you might be following a very old tutorial stat teaches you a style of redux that will end up being a multitude longer than actually required.
Please follow the official tutorials: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index to learn how to write modern redux from the start.

Comment: Thanks phry, yes i am new to redux and learning using tutorials on linked in and youtube.

Comment: Yeah, feared so. Please really go with the official tutorials. 
Modern redux has no need for type string constans, no manually written actions or action creators, no switch-case statements and no hand-written immutable logic. Also we recommend learning the react-redux hooks over connect, as it is a lot easier to learn.